# Assigning random partnership without repeating?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

Question narrowed to the following:

I have two arrays: `user_in_need` and `active_users`.  `user_in_need` is a subset of `active_users`.

```
Array ( [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9] )  // active_users

Array ( [3]  [7]  [9] )                                // user_in_need
```

I need to randomly assign to each `user_in_need` a partner from the `active_users` array.  The one caveat, I cannot have a user be assigned himself as partner.

This is as far as I've been able to get [doesn't work]:

```
$partners = array();
foreach ($user_in_need as $value) {
    $key = array_search($value, $active_users);
    unset($active_users[$key]);

    shuffle($active_users);
    $newpartner = end($active_users);

    $partners[$value] = $newpartner;
    $user = $value;

    $query = "UPDATE users SET target=:partner WHERE uid=:uid";
    $query_params = array(':partner' => $newpartner, ':uid' => $user );
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
```

Comment: The only problem with my code as it stands is that unsetting the value is persistent.  So, going with my hypothetical list of user ids: after `3` is removed from the `active_users` array, it stays removed while `7` is processed, and then `3` & `7` are absent when `9` is processsed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this "pseudo code" in pseudo english:

- Get current partners

```php
<?php
SELECT partner_id FROM users WHERE user_id = USER_ID

do{
    $partners[] = $row['partner_id']
}
?>
```

- Now select the available users that aren't himself or already partners with something like:

```php
<?php
SELECT user_id  FROM users WHERE user_id != USER_ID AND partner_id NOT IN ( implode(', ', $partners) )
?>
```

Job done!?

Comment: This idea requires a ton of database queries. It isn't efficient at all.

Comment: If you actually wrote the code, you'd see the excess of code and queries.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think I'd ever manage to figure it out on my own, but here it is:

All that needed to be done is to remove the value from the `active_users` array as I had done, perform the required actions, then, after everything was finished, just add the value back into `active_users` before the loop ended--thereby restoring it to it's original state.

So, I just added: `$theliving[] = $value;` immediately before the query.